# Node.js & socket.io messaging app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, chat, message

Im new to nodejs and everything related so be patient with me )

Im trying to make a messaging app, so far Ive read a lot of chat tutorials using **socket.io** and eventually made one. what I want now is to make a **messaging** app using node.js and I have no idea where to start and which frameworks to use. I believe I can make it using **socket.io** rooms (any tips related to this also would be very helpful).

Here is what Im looking for:

- one-to-one messages
- group messages
- notifications

What framework/programming language should I use? what is the best practice in terms of **security** and **performance**

Should I use **NODE.JS** at all or  go with **PHP** based messaging?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: socket.io supports the first two of your requirements. Security is not something you get through frameworks, and performance only matters if you can measure it, e.g. after you have implemented something. So, unless you can define your requirements in more clear terms, I am afraid this is too broad of a question.

Comment: @verybadalloc, I know that I can make messaging app using socket.io and it meets my requirements but the question is what are the best practices in terms of performance and security? *gonna clearify the question...

Comment: @verybadalloc 
I clarified the question...
So far I have a chat and it works well, but I cannot figure out how to get notified if someone leaves a message in a room and am on main page (eg not in any room) should I join all rooms to get notified?